# PHP preg_match problem

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

**content.tpl**

```
tratata 'hey' tratata <br/>
okay 'aaaaa' <br/>
'trtata' <br/>
echo 'tratata'hmmmm'traatata';
'hello' tratata <br/>
```

How do I change all the quotes ONLY in the echo?

I need

```
tratata 'hey' tratata <br/>
okay 'aaaaa' <br/>
'trtata' <br/>
echo 'tratata\'hmmmm\'traatata';
'hello' tratata <br/>
```

Thank you

Comment: I haven't got the slightest clue what you are asking. Could you give a real world example?

Comment: @lonesomeday: It's pretty clear to me.

Comment: @Vincent Glad to hear it! I get the basic point, but I don't understand the example, which is pretty much gobbledegook -- what's the purpose of this escaping?

Comment: @lonesomeday: So that the echo works correctly. He probably generated this code and want to fix it.

Comment: @Vincent The echo will work correctly, but this still won't be valid PHP.

Comment: @lonesomeday: Obviously. I don't know exactly what he wants to do after, I just provided a way to do the first step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty easy with a callback :

```
$var = preg_replace_callback("`(?<=echo ')(.+)(?=';)`iU", function ($matches) { return addslashes($matches[1]); }, $var)
```

First, we match the echo quoted string (and nothing else), then we apply the addslashes function on what we found. The ungreedy (U) option is important so the .+ doesn't match the whole string.